# Cannot Remove Underline From Vue router-link

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, routerlink

I think I tried almost everything trying to remove underline from `router-link`.

This is my code:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">
   <div>Plan Your Trip</div>
      <div class='expander'>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">COVID-19</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">Visa</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">Essentials</router-link>
   </div>
</router-link>
```

I'm trying to remove underline from *sub-links* only.

**Things I've tried:**

*In-line style*

```
<router-link style="text-decoration: none !important;" :to="{name: 'Plan'}">COVID-19</router-link>
```

*Assign class*

```
<router-link class="sub-link" :to="{name: 'Plan'}">COVID-19</router-link>

<style scoped>
   .sub-link{text-decoration: none !important;}
</style>
```

*Declare tag*

```
<router-link tag="div" :to="{name: 'Plan'}">COVID-19</router-link>

<style scoped>
   div{text-decoration: none !important;}
</style>
```

*Assign seperate tag* + *Declare class for that tag*

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">
   <div class="sub-link">COVID-19</div>
</router-link>
```

**These are just few lists**, I literally tried every possible methods I can think of... Am I missing something about customizing Vue `router-link`?

Comment: Can you inspect that element in DOM and post that snip? It is working here https://jsfiddle.net/kxec8s0L/

Comment: Yes, I already tried that as well. There's the screenshot. http://prntscr.com/u3lvix. I don't know why there's empty 'class' declared in DOM though?

Comment: `.expander a { text-decoration: none !important}` Can you try this css once

Comment: No luck on that as well :( But frankly, other declared styles are working though...? Just not 'text-decoration'...  http://prntscr.com/u3lzui

Comment: That's very weird

Comment: Out of curiosity, when is this underline occuring? on hover?

Comment: Yea.... I spend well over an hour on this :*( I tried many other methods as well like: decaring global css from App.js, v-bind:style, etc...

Comment: I didn't set it to happen on any event. It's just a default behavior. I just removed default color and set it to 'white'.

Comment: Please check the browser dev tools. Click on the `Elements ` tab and switch from `Styles` to `Computed`. I have a feeling that a style is overriding it. It seems that you use the `important` keyword a few times.

Comment: hmm... http://prntscr.com/u3m66t

Comment: Accepted answer has resolved the issue. It's really weird.. but thanks all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uses `display: inline-block;text-decoration:none;`, the trick is **display: inline-block;**.

[Css spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props) states

> For block containers that establish an inline formatting context, the
> decorations are propagated to an anonymous inline element that wraps
> all the in-flow inline-level children of the block container. For all
> other elements it is propagated to any in-flow children. Note that
> text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely
> positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level
> descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

**Example**: The link `COVID-19` in your codes will remove the underline.

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">
   <div>Plan Your Trip</div>
      <div class='expander'>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}" style="display: inline-block;text-decoration:none;">COVID-19</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">Visa</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">Essentials</router-link>
   </div>
</router-link>
```

Below is one demo:

```js
let Layout = {
  template: `<div>
  <h4>Layout Page </h4>
  <router-link to="/contact">
  <div>
    <p>Links<p>
    <router-link to="/contact/add" style="display: inline-block;text-decoration:none;">Add1</router-link>
    <router-link to="/addcontact">Add2</router-link>
  </div>
  </router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
  </div>`
};
let Home = {
  template: '<div>this is the home page. Go to <router-link to="/contact">contact</router-link> </div>'
};

let ContactList = {
  // add <router-view> in order to load children route of path='/contact'
  template: '<div>this is contact list, click <router-link to="/contact/add">Add Contact In sub Router-View</router-link> here to add contact<p><router-view></router-view></p> Or Click <router-link to="/addcontact">Add Contact In Current Router-View</router-link></div>'
};

let ContactAdd = {
  template: '<div>Contact Add</div>'
}

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    redirect: 'home',
    component: Layout,
    children: [{
        path: 'home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactList,
        children: [{
          path: 'add',
          component: ContactAdd
        }]
      },
      {
        path: 'addcontact', // or move ContactAdd as direct child route of path=`/`
        component: ContactAdd,
      }
    ]
  }]
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'App': {
      template: '<div><router-view></router-view></div>'
    },
  },
  router
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.0.1/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<section id="app">
  <app></app>
</section>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Could you please explain how this approach worked?

Comment: [Css spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props) states underline will not be applied for inline block whose parent element already been set `text-decoration: underline`

Comment: I thought it was Vue issue, but it was CSS wow! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the DOM for a router-link, you see that it's an `a` tag. Bear in mind, that even when the initial underline is removed, there is an underline that happens when you hover over the router link text.

Using this snippet

```html
<router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">
   <div>Plan Your Trip</div>
      <div class='expander'>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">COVID-19</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">Visa</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name: 'Plan'}">Essentials</router-link>
   </div>
</router-link>
```

```css
.expander a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.expander a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer `router-link` is applying `text-decoration: underline` to its inner-text and the inner `router-link`s are also applying `text-decoration: underline` to their inner-text.

You essentially have double underlines applied to your inner `router-links` at the moment.

You need to remove it from both. If you need another element to have `text-decoration: underline` then set it for that element separately.